# Why is there only one USDT which PoS?

Tags: tokens, polygon, usdt

In Polygon wheneer I deal with USDT, it's always **PoS**. There's no ordinary USDT - without PoS remark, though.

Are all USDT in Polygon PoS ones?  Or are there other types too?

Or did there use to be ordinary USDTs too, but nowadays there've switched to USDT **PoS** completely?

My question is only about Polygon.

Answer (score 1):

PoS refers to having been bridged via Polygon Proof of Stake bridge, alternative to Polygon Plasma bridge.

This page seem to have been moved or removed, but using the way back machine we can add some context.

> There are primarily two bridges to move assets between Ethereum and Polygon. First one is the Plasma bridge and the second one is called the PoS Bridge or Proof of Stake bridge. Plasma bridge provides increased security guarantees due to the Plasma exit mechanism.

> However, there are certain restrictions on the child token and there is a 7-day withdrawal period associated with all exits/withdraws from Polygon to Ethereum on the Plasma bridge. The PoS Bridge is more flexible and features faster withdrawals.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230324090339/https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/plasma/getting-started/

In practice a majority of liquidity seemed to move in PoS tokens.
It is "ordinary USDT" in as much as any bridged token that can be unwrapped to the underlying asset via bridging back to the chain it came from.

That said there is USDT bridged via other bridges on Polygon, from BSC you can get Binance pegged USDT, and similar, but you won't find much liquidity for those tokens. On most chains the liquidity will be in the asset bridged directly from Ethereum as that is usually where the contract holding the locked tokens is.

Comment: In Polygon, can USDT be sent to PoS USDT address? Will it arrive? And vice versa

Comment: Tokens and token addresses aren't interchangeable. Someone might redeem one for another like circle issued usdc bridged to arbitrum from ethereum, vs circle issued usdc on arbitrum. Coinbase will take both, but they aren't interchangeable with any smart contract like staking contracts etc.

Comment: In Polygon, can USDT be sent to PoS USDT address? Will it arrive? And vice versa